# Process Builder not triggered after record creation via API

Tags: api, integration, process, builder

I have a process builder that is triggered upon record creation of an opportunity.  If I manually create the opportunity, the process builder runs fine.  When the opportunity is created from an integration via API, the process builder doesn't get triggered.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any criteria in process builder

Comment: please post the entry criteria to the Process Builder flow as well as under what conditions the flow is even considered for evaluation. Use the [edit] link and post screen shots

Comment: The only entry criteria is when "Shipping Cost > $0.00."  Shipping cost is a custom field on the Oppty detail record that gets populated from the eCommerce application that we have integrated with.